# MVC 5 RegularExpression Phone Number

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches theese cases.

Phone number can be: 8 digits 0-9 OR 12 digits 0-9 OR 12 digits 0-9 and a + sign
So: 12345678, 0012345678, +0012345678 are valid options

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]{8})|[0-9]+{12}|[0-9]{11}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid phone")]
```

Would also be nice that on the + validation case, the plus sign have to be in the beginning (following 10 digits) and on the 12 digits validation there have to be 00 first (then following 10 digits)

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: @stibay You mean there may be `+` sign before the number?

Comment: Yes, if you have a + sign. It have to be in the beginning and following 10 digits. F.ex +4712345678

Comment: Almost got it working now. [RegularExpression(@"^\d{8}|00\d{10}|\+\d{2}\d{8}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")] Only the middle part is not working. The 00XXXXXXXXXX is still invalid :/

Comment: put them all into a non-capturing group, like `@"^(?:\d{8}|00\d{10}|\+\d{2}\d{8})$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
@"^(?:\d{8}|00\d{10}|\+\d{2}\d{8})$"
```

Comment: Almost perfect. 0012345678 should not be valid. Ended up with using Avinash comment, (@"^(?:\d{8}|00\d{10}|\+\d{2}\d{8})$"

Comment: @stibay updated my answer. I'm the one who posted the above comment.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]{8}|00[0-9]{10}|/+00[0-9]{11}
```

Comment: I get an error on the + sign. Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: @stibay whoops sry, in C# thats \ is the escape sequence, try it now with / as the escape sequence

Comment: I am using C#, I figgured out that it was because I neede at @ at the start to allow for using \ as the escape character. Other option was to double \\

Comment: The regex looks like this. But it still doesnt work correct. [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{8})|00[0-9]{12}|\+00[0-9]{11}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")] 004712345678 and +4712345678 says that it is invalid. Only 12345678 works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
[RegularExpression("^(\+)?(\d{2})?\d{8}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid phone")]
```